# Drag formula down and change the reference of the column (index+match)

Tags: excel-formula

I need help with the following formula:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!A2:A11,MATCH(Sheet1!Q5,Sheet2!C2:C11,0)+0)
```

(this part needs to change column references: `Sheet2!C2:C11,0)+0)`

I need to change the column reference whenever I'm dragging it down. I tried this:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$12,MATCH(Sheet1!Q4,OFFSET(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$12,0,ROW(O$4:O4)-1),0)+0)
```

but it always comes up with `#N/A`

I tried solution from other topics but couldn't find one that uses `index` and `match`.

PS. My formula starts from cell `O5`

Can you advise please?

Much obliged

Comment: I would advise changing formulas to [R1C1](https://excelchamps.com/blog/r1c1-reference-style/) style then you just reference row absolutely but make the column call relative (read from further down the link I gave to see how absolute referencing works with this formula style)

Comment: Isn't there an option to avoid R1C1 (also to avoid VBA)?

Comment: You could try build an array for `Match()` using `IF(COLUMN() = ROW())` etc. pretty busy atm though so feel free to give it a go and name drop me to help out after office hours (Ctrl+Shift+Enter, not just enter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if you want to change the column reference when dragging down, use a combination of `INDEX` and `ROW`, e.g.

```
= INDEX($1:$1,ROW())
```

This will grab values further to the right in the first row as the formula is dragged down.

You can also modify this to have `INDEX` return a *range* (instead of just a single cell) to be used as part of another formula, e.g.

```
= INDEX($1:$5,0,ROW())
```

This returns a 5x1 array which shifts over to the right as the formula is dragged down. (The `0` in the above formula indicates to select *all* of the rows in the `$1:$5` range.)

In your formula, you can try replacing this:

```
Sheet2!C2:C11
```

With this:

```
INDEX(Sheet2!$2:$11,0,ROW()+<offset>)
```

Where `<offset>` is the necessary offset that you need.

If your formula starts in `O5` and you want that first formula to grab the `C` column, I imagine that `<offset>` should be `-2`. This is because `ROW()` of `O5` is `5`, but you want that cell to grab the 3rd column (so you need to subtract 2). Then when you drag down to `O6`, that part of the formula would evaluate to `Sheet2!D2:D11`, and in cell `O7`, it would evaluate to `Sheet2!E2:E11`, etc.

So your final formula should be:

```
= INDEX(Sheet2!A2:A11,MATCH(Sheet1!Q3,INDEX(Sheet2!$2:$11,0,ROW()-2),0)+0)
```

Comment: Thanks for your exhaustive response :) Can you please advise why the formula breaks when I change Sheet1!Q3 to Sheet1!Q5 ?

Comment: `Sheet1!Q3` vs. `Sheet1!Q5` has no inherent tie-in to my explanation. I'm guessing the formula breaks just because a match value cannot be found, but that is just a guess because I have no idea what your data is.

Comment: So, I have tried your solution and am still facing errors. Perhaps am doing something wrong? I would employ your formula (and it works for that specific scenario), however as soon as I start dragging it down it all fails.

Comment: Maybe try changing them all to absolute references? i.e. change `Sheet2!A2:A11` to `Sheet2!$A$2:$A$11` and `Sheet1!Q3` to `Sheet1!$Q$3`. Again, I'm basically guessing at this point because I have no idea what your data is. If you provide more  details in your questions, I can provide a more appropriate response.

Comment: My initial formula was fine INDEX(Sheet2!A2:A11,MATCH(Sheet1!Q5,Sheet2!C2:C11,0)+0), I simply locked the initial range Sheet2!A2:A11 Thanks a lot for your help IH